# Mysql select json

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table where one column is a json, like this:

```
{"type":"select","description":"Rota","default":"",
"required":"0","listOptions":[{"text": "1 - Jardins", "value": "1"}, {"text": "2 - Praia do Canto/Shop Vix", "value": "2"}, {"text": "3 - Hotéis Vitória/Serra", "value": "3"}, {"text": "6 - Hotéis Vila Velha/Padarias Praia da Costa", "value": "6"}, {"text": "9 - Cariacica", "value": "9"}, {"text": "5 - Vitória/Vila Velha", "value": "5"}, {"text": "10 - Baú/Reboque", "value": "10"}}
```

I can select like this: `select atributos->"$.listOptions" from table`

My question is, how can I select the values from `listOptions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[*]` to extract all the array item values.

```
SELECT  atributos->"$.listOptions[*].value" FROM test;
```

To extract a specify item use e.g first item value.

```
SELECT  atributos->"$.listOptions[0].value" FROM test;
```

Refer to [Runnable DBFiddle instance](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6TCt2h43GvRDYDZnVdmdTc/0).

Comment: Can i use some filter using $.listOptions[*].value?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql 8 you can use [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)

> ```
> CREATE tABLE TAB1 (atributos json);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES ('{"type":"select","description":"Rota","default":"",
> "required":"0","listOptions":[{"text": "1 - Jardins", "value": "1"}, {"text": "2 - Praia do Canto/Shop Vix", "value": "2"}, {"text": "3 - Hotéis Vitória/Serra", "value": "3"}, {"text": "6 - Hotéis Vila Velha/Padarias Praia da Costa", "value": "6"}, {"text": "9 - Cariacica", "value": "9"}, {"text": "5 - Vitória/Vila Velha", "value": "5"}, {"text": "10 - Baú/Reboque", "value": "10"}]}');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT atributos->"$.description", tt1.*
>      FROM TAB1,
>        JSON_TABLE(
>          atributos,
>          "$.listOptions[*]"
>         COLUMNS (
>            mytext VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.text" DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY DEFAULT '-99' ON ERROR,
>            myvalue INT PATH "$.value" 
>        ) ) tt1;
> ```
>
> ```
> atributos->"$.description" | mytext                                         | myvalue
> :------------------------- | :--------------------------------------------- | ------:
> "Rota"                     | 1 - Jardins                                    |       1
> "Rota"                     | 2 - Praia do Canto/Shop Vix                    |       2
> "Rota"                     | 3 - Hotéis Vitória/Serra                     |       3
> "Rota"                     | 6 - Hotéis Vila Velha/Padarias Praia da Costa |       6
> "Rota"                     | 9 - Cariacica                                  |       9
> "Rota"                     | 5 - Vitória/Vila Velha                        |       5
> "Rota"                     | 10 - Baú/Reboque                              |      10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39917ebf6775919456b564246d500ee1)*

Answer (score 0):

- mysql Server (since Version 8.0):

  ```
  SELECT [field with json blob]->>"$.json_field" FROM mytable;
  ```
- mariaDB Server (since Version 10.26)

  ```
   SELECT JSON_EXTRACT([field with json blob], "$.json_field") from mytable
  ```